# how printk is implemented while booting

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, uart, printk

I am porting latest version Linux (linux-stable) to a customized ARM926TEJ-S board, and I want to print messages in the initializing phase. So I am trobuled by the problems of how can i let the uart work in the kernel initializing phase.

[printing linux banner in init/main.c:start_kernel()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L504)
eventually call `printk()` to print the message. My question is how the `printk()` is implemented and how can I let the `printk()` output to my uart.

Because I know the driver of uart is not initialized there, they are initialize by `rest_init()` called in the end of start_kernel(). `rest_init()` will consequently call `do_initcalls()` and eventually call `module_init()` of drivers.

And I know [putstr("Uncompressing Linux...");](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/compressed/misc.c#L161) in the uncompressing phase is implemented by `arch/arm/boot/compressed/debug.S` that using `waituart/senduart...` that implemented by the files setting by `CONFIG_DEBUG_LL_INCLUDE`

Comment: Study `earlyprintk`, which redirects output from the console buffer to a predefined serial port, e.g. the same device that the decompressor used.  See https://falstaff.agner.ch/2015/10/17/linux-earlyprintkearlycon-support-on-arm/  Note that earlyprintk can be implemented with earlycon.

Comment: thanks sawdust, I know a little about `earlyprintk`. but I instead of using `earlyprintk` , I looked into the memory of `__log_buf`. So I can read the messages printed by `printk` now. And I think if `earlyprintk` is not enabled, the contents printed by `printk` will be in the buffer only till the console is registered. is it right?

Comment: There are basically two mechanisms and they are different: `earliprintk` (legacy), and `earlycon`. The latter is using the real driver of the console after decompressing is done. Any console which is provided by DeviceTree would be used.